# How to run multiple java class files from command prompt?

Tags: java, cmd

I have multiple java files in a single directory that are related to a single program (Main). I have been using the following in the command prompt,

`javac -cp . game/textbased/*.java`

`java -cp . game/textbased/Main`

All related files are in a package called game.textbased. The parent folder series is textbasedgame/src/game/textbased.

I am not sure what is going wrong, the java files seem to compile as nessessary, however, when I try to run I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: items.dat (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
        at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
        at game.textbased.WonderLand.loadItems(WonderLand.java:310)
        at game.textbased.WonderLand.initGame(WonderLand.java:63)
        at game.textbased.WonderLand.<init>(WonderLand.java:24)
        at game.textbased.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

I am really not sure what is going wrong, and how to run the files from here. I have read other stack overflow inqueries of a similar nature, and generally they say to go from a higher directory but that has not been working for me. I tried going from outside src, or from within the textbased folder, but only going from within the src folder has given me this particular error.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is the Java program is looking for a file `" items.dat "` and it can't find it.  Where is this file?

Comment: In a parent folder - Should it be included in the folder with the otehr java/class files?

Comment: On line 310 of Wonderland.java, you're trying to open a file called "items.dat".  Does your program specify what directory to look in for that file?  If not, then your program is looking for that file in whatever directory you're in when you run the program.

Comment: Dawood gave the answer.  As an aside, in Java we often use resources to help with the problem of "where to find data X?" when running a Java program.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Comment: Load your file using `new InputStreamReader(Wonderland.class.getResourceAsStream("items.dat"))` instead of using FileReader.  That will always read items.dat from the directory where your .class files are located, so you won’t have to depend on the current directory at all.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post (at least) the code for method `loadItems` in class `game.textbased.WonderLand`.